# How to retrieve Apple IDFA in Flutter?

Tags: mobile, flutter, idfa, google-advertising-id

How i can retrieve Apple IDFA in Flutter App? I have already tried advertising_id plugin, but it crashes on Android and doesn't retrieve ID at IOS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you check [this package](https://pub.dev/packages/advertising_id#-installing-tab-)?

First add the package to your dependencies (pubspec.yaml)

```
dependencies:
  advertising_id: ^0.9.2
```

Then run get packages to install it. Then add it to your file:

```
import 'package:advertising_id/advertising_id.dart';
```

Then use it like:

```
print(await AdvertisingId.id);
```

I checked it and I couldn't make it work on iOS but it is working on Android. I hope this helps.

Comment: Ensure to update your info.plist file to ensure the package works for iOS, simply include a usage description  <key>NSUserTrackingUsageDescription</key>
<string>Usage Description</string>

Comment: I am not able to run it on android. can you tell me which version of kotlin are you using?

Comment: @Ankit hey man, this was long ago I am not sure about the version.